# Radio Button form to change variables on PHP file

Tags: php, html, forms, variables

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is a simple PHP on/off where I have PHP code which is set to 0 but have the ability to change it to a 1 or 0 from a form.

```
 PHP file| $settingon = 1 //1 for active, 0 for inactive
HTML file| <form action="php/settingfile.php">
       <input type="radio" name="settingon" value="1"> Active<br>
       <input type="radio" name="settingon" value="0"> Inactive<br>
       <button type="submit">Save Settings</button>
       </form>
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @s3nzoM when i submit it i want it to change the $settingon to a 1 or 0 depending on the radio selected

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the input:

```
<form action="php/settingfile.php">
    <input type="radio" name="settingon" <?php $settingon? "":"disabled" ?>> Active<br>
    <button type="submit">Save Settings</button>
</form>
```

or create a class that displays the input as you want:

```
<form action="php/settingfile.php">
    <input type="radio" name="settingon" class="<?php $settingon? "active":"inactive" ?>"> Active<br>
    <button type="submit">Save Settings</button>
</form>
```